# Nasdaq.com исторические котировки через VBA POST

Tags: javascript, post, vba

Привет всем!
Стоит задача собрать исторические котировки по бумаге с сайта nasdaq.com для дальнейшей их обработки и вывода отчета в MS Excel. Язык - VBA.
Собственно, в консоли браузера IE и Chrome удалось выяснить, что обмен необходимой информацией идет по методу POST, тело запроса, что подтверждается синтаксисом соответствующей функции JavaScript на самой странице, следующего типа:

```
[период]|[с загрузкой или без]|[тикер бумаги большими буквами]
```

, например, тело запроса `5d|false|AAPL` должно в формате json передать информацию о котировках компании APPLE за период последние 5 дней.

Вот синтаксис функции на самой странице, которая вызывается для запроса исторических котировок:

```
function getQuotes(download) {
        if (!download)
            showLoadingSpinner();

        var data = $("[id$='ddlTimeFrame']").val();
        var submitString = data + '|' + download + "|" + quoteBoxSelectedSymbol; if (!download) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl,
                data: submitString,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("[id$='historicalContainer']").html(response);
                    $(".genTable tbody tr:odd").addClass("genTablealt");
                    hideLoadingSpinner();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $("[id$='submitString']").val(submitString);
            $("#getFile").submit();
        }
    }
```

Далее, я постарался написать функцию VBA, которая бы "эмулировала" такой-же запрос на сервер:

```
'POST-запрос на сервер
Public Function POST(reff As Variant, body As Variant, headers() As String)
    'reff - адрес сервера
    'body - тело запроса
    'Headers  - массив заголовков. Двухмерный. 1-й столбец - название заголовка, 2-й столбец - значение

    Dim oHttp As Object
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    oHttp.Open "POST", CStr(reff)
    'заголовки
    For Ii = 1 To UBound(headers)
        If headers(Ii, 1) <> Empty Then
            oHttp.setRequestHeader CStr(headers(Ii, 1)), CStr(headers(Ii, 2))
        End If
    Next Ii
    oHttp.send CStr(body)

    'выводим результат
    POST = oHttp.responseText

End Function
```

здесь, в строке `oHttp.send CStr(body)`

как раз и передается тело запроса `5d|false|AAPL` в переменной body.
В качестве адреса, куда отправляется запрос, использовался адрес самой страницы с котировками.

> http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/historical

В качестве заголовков (массив headers()), брались:

> Content-Type -> application/json
>
> X-Requested-With -> XMLHttpRequest

что имеем в итоге:
при запуске происходит "зависание" функции где-то секунд на 30. После чего возвращается ошибка "Время ожидания истекло" на строке кода `oHttp.send CStr(body)`
Помогите решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Возвожно, были проблемы с сайтом... Возможно, неправильно вызываете функцию.

```
Sub kk()
Dim hdr(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As String
    hdr(1, 1) = "Content-Type": hdr(1, 2) = "application/json"
    hdr(2, 1) = "X-Requested-With": hdr(2, 2) = "XMLHttpRequest"
    Debug.Print POST("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/historical", "5d|false|AAPL", hdr)
End Sub
```

Функция выдала результат в *Immediate Window* практически мгновенно:

```
   <div id="quotes_content_left_pnlAJAX">

                <h3 class="table-headtag">
                    Results for: 5 Days, From 
    10-OCT-2017  TO 16-OCT-2017 
                </h3>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Open</th>
                            <th>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tt show-link" id="high" onmouseover="showDelayedToolTip('high')" onmouseout="hideToolTip('high')">
                                    High
                                    <span class="tooltipLG">
                                        <span class="topLG"></span>
                                        <span class="middleLG">
                                            "High" is the highest sales price the stock has achieved during the regular trading hours, the intra-day high.
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="bottomLG"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tt show-link" id="low" onmouseover="showDelayedToolTip('low')" onmouseout="hideToolTip('low')">
                                    Low
                                    <span class="tooltipLG">
                                        <span class="topLG"></span>
                                        <span class="middleLG">
                                            "Low" is the lowest sales price the stock has fallen to during the regular trading hours, the intra-day low.
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="bottomLG"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tt show-link" id="close_last" onmouseover="showDelayedToolTip('close_last')" onmouseout="hideToolTip('close_last')">
                                    Close / Last
                                    <span class="tooltipLG">
                                        <span class="topLG"></span>
                                        <span class="middleLG">
                                            "Close" is the period at the end of the trading session. Sometimes used to refer to closing price.
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="bottomLG"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tt show-link" id="volume" onmouseover="showDelayedToolTip('volume')" onmouseout="hideToolTip('volume')">
                                    Volume
                                    <span class="tooltipLG">
                                        <span class="topLG"></span>
                                        <span class="middleLG">
                                            "Volume" The closing daily official volumes represented graphically for each trading day.
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="bottomLG"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                15:09
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                159.86
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                160.87
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                159.23
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                160.2061
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                15,149,124
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        10/16/2017
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        157.9
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        160
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        157.65
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        159.88
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        24,093,300
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        10/13/2017
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        156.73
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        157.28
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        156.41
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        156.99
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        16,367,780
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        10/12/2017
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        156.35
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        157.37
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        155.7299
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        156
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        16,380,570
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        10/11/2017
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        155.97
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        156.98
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        155.75
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        156.55
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        16,861,450
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        10/10/2017
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        156.055
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        158
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        155.1
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        155.9
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        15,603,520
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: **vikttur**, сделал в точности как вы приводите. ошибка та же самая: зависание не 30 сек. и сообщение "Время ожидания истекло"...даже не знаю, что может быть не так. Может какую библиотеку не подключил?

Comment: Вот мой список: Visual Basic For Applications, Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library, OLE Automation, Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library, Microsoft Forms 2.0Object Library, Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library, Microsoft HTML Object Library, Microsoft Internet Controls, Microsoft WinHTTP Services ver. 5.1,  AdHocReportingExcelClientLib, Microsoft Terminal Services Control Type Library, Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for the Microsoft Office, Microsoft OLE DB Simple Provider 1.5 Library, Microsoft ADO Ext 6.0 for DDL and Security, Microsoft XML v 3.0

Comment: У меня подключены только первые 4. Различие - вместо 15.0 имеют индекс 14.0

Comment: Проверьте на другой машине. Еще вариант: проверить на другой версии Офиса. В Excel-2016 наблюдаются всякие неприятности. У меня 2010, отработало без проблем.

Comment: А вот на другой машине все работает. Как вы и сказали ответ с нужной информацией приходит почти мгновенно. Интересно, что это может быть? Фаерволл? служба безопасности?

Comment: Могу только предполагать. Для проверки отключайте по очереди. Может быть, Офис (в частности - *Excel*) установлен криво...